# Port 51347 seems to be used by another program

Tags: sockets, distributed-computing, dispy

On running the sample code given in the dispy documentation

`def compute(n):
    import time, socket
    time.sleep(n)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    return (host, n)
if name == 'main':
    import dispy, random
    cluster = dispy.JobCluster(compute)
    jobs = []
    for i in range(10):
        # schedule execution of 'compute' on a node (running 'dispynode')
        # with a parameter (random number in this case)
        job = cluster.submit(random.randint(5,20))
        job.id = i # optionally associate an ID to job (if needed later)
        jobs.append(job)
    # cluster.wait() # wait for all scheduled jobs to finish
    for job in jobs:
        host, n = job() # waits for job to finish and returns results
        print('%s executed job %s at %s with %s' % (host, job.id, job.start_time, n))
        # other fields of 'job' that may be useful:
        # print(job.stdout, job.stderr, job.exception, job.ip_addr, job.start_time, job.end_time)
    cluster.print_status()`

I get the following output

2017-03-29 22:39:52 asyncoro - version 4.5.2 with epoll I/O notifier

2017-03-29 22:39:52 dispy - dispy client version: 4.7.3

2017-03-29 22:39:52 dispy - Port 51347 seems to be used by another program

And then nothing happens.
How to free the 51347 port?

Answer (score 1):

If you are under Linux, run `sudo netstat -tuanp | grep 51347` and take note of the pid using that port.

Then execute `ps ax | grep <pid>` to check which service/program is running with that pid.

Then execute `kill <pid>` to terminate the process using that port.

**Please check which process is using the port before killing it just in case it is something that you should not kill.**