# Python - dispy Port 51347 seems to be used by another program

Tags: python, distributed-computing, dispy

I am trying to run the program on the dispy page (http://dispy.sourceforge.net/) and I know this question is very similar to this one once asked ([Port 51347 seems to be used by another program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100081/port-51347-seems-to-be-used-by-another-program)), but please do not file as duplicate because I have tried the answer given there and it doesn't fix the problem. I ran netstat and couldn't find any program running on the port 51347.

I tried running the program on several different ports, but every time i tried to run it using a localhost IP it kept giving me the same error 'Port xxxx seems to be used by another program'. I tried using it with a different IP and it didn't give me an error but then the code waits for an input from that IP rather than simply running locally.

Has anyone else had this problem that found a fix?